# How to resample and calculate amount weighted average price in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of trades in which each trade has a corresponding amount and price. How can I resample the dataframe in a 1 minute period and calculate the amount weighted average prices of each period ?

```
>df
                          amount     price
datetime                                  
2023-06-23 10:55:40.420  0.04657  30106.01
2023-06-23 10:55:42.348  0.00085  30104.54
2023-06-23 10:55:42.491  0.00368  30104.54
2023-06-23 10:55:43.211  0.03008  30104.54
2023-06-23 10:55:45.910  0.00035  30101.56
...                          ...       ...
2023-06-23 10:58:06.401  0.00863  30108.00
2023-06-23 10:58:06.661  0.00829  30108.00
2023-06-23 10:58:07.474  0.00305  30108.00
2023-06-23 10:58:07.599  0.00048  30108.00
2023-06-23 10:58:08.393  0.00041  30108.00

[428 rows x 2 columns]
```

I can resample trade amounts with :

```
>>> df['amount'].resample("1Min").sum()
datetime
2023-06-23 10:55:00     0.78885
2023-06-23 10:56:00    12.84216
2023-06-23 10:57:00     9.56456
2023-06-23 10:58:00     0.08334
Freq: T, Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

But what is the best solution to calculate the average price of each periods based on the amount of each trade ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the average of amount*price and divide by the sum of amount per period:

```
(df.eval('product = amount*price')[['amount', 'product']]
   .resample("1Min").sum()
   .eval('product/amount')
)
```

Output:

```
datetime
2023-06-23 10:55:00    30105.366872
2023-06-23 10:56:00             NaN
2023-06-23 10:57:00             NaN
2023-06-23 10:58:00    30108.000000
Freq: T, dtype: float64
```

Intermediate before the last step (`.eval('product/amount')`):

```
                      amount      product
datetime                                 
2023-06-23 10:55:00  0.08153  2454.490561
2023-06-23 10:56:00  0.00000     0.000000
2023-06-23 10:57:00  0.00000     0.000000
2023-06-23 10:58:00  0.02086   628.052880
```

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted to do, thanks

Comment: This is fully arbitrary, you mentioned "*what is the best solution to calculate the **average price** of each periods*", thus the name. The final output is however not a product of price and amount, only the intermediate before division is. Just call it "product" if this is easier ;)